# Unable to load NetCDF files into GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, netcdf

I run WRF models that provides output in netcdf. I want the NetCDF files to be loaded into GeoServer so that I can use it with WMS. I used ncks to extract only the temperature variable T2 in the output NetCDF file.

I installed the NetCDF plugin from the GeoServer website but it gives following when adding the file as a datasource

```
Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:wrfout_d03_2023-01-05_00.nc and hints Hints: EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@5175ae63[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@127fa4ef System defaults: COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@53b1a3f8 LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl
```

The GeoServer logs shows this error message.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create reader from file:wrfout_d03_2023-01-05_00.nc and hints Hints:
  EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@5175ae63[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
  REPOSITORY       = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@127fa4ef                                                                                   
System defaults:
  COMPARISON_TOLERANCE             = 1.0E-8                                                 
  FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING        = http                                                   
  GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY            = GridCoverageFactory                                    
    TILE_ENCODING                  = null                                                   
  FEATURE_FACTORY                  = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@53b1a3f8
  LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT              = true                                                   
  FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true                                                   
  FILTER_FACTORY                   = FilterFactoryImpl                                      
  STYLE_FACTORY                    = StyleFactoryImpl                                       

    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1596)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1534)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageStoreInfoImpl.getGridCoverageReader(CoverageStoreInfoImpl.java:57)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:144)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.getGridCoverageReader(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItemsInternal(NewLayerPageProvider.java:98)
    ... 158 more
```

I downloaded a sample nc file from unidata.ucar.edu and it gets loaded fine. Both files have similar dimensions. Ncdump of both files are shown below

Mywrfoutfile.nc

```
netcdf tempall {
dimensions:
    Time = UNLIMITED ; // (73 currently)
    south_north = 243 ;
    west_east = 315 ;
variables:
    float T2(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        T2:FieldType = 104 ;
        T2:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        T2:description = "TEMP at 2 M" ;
        T2:units = "K" ;
        T2:stagger = "" ;
        T2:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float XLAT(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        XLAT:FieldType = 104 ;
        XLAT:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        XLAT:description = "LATITUDE, SOUTH IS NEGATIVE" ;
        XLAT:units = "degree_north" ;
        XLAT:stagger = "" ;
        XLAT:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT" ;
    float XLONG(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        XLONG:FieldType = 104 ;
        XLONG:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        XLONG:description = "LONGITUDE, WEST IS NEGATIVE" ;
        XLONG:units = "degree_east" ;
        XLONG:stagger = "" ;
        XLONG:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT" ;
    float XTIME(Time) ;
        XTIME:FieldType = 104 ;
        XTIME:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        XTIME:description = "minutes since 2023-01-01 00:00:00" ;
        XTIME:units = "minutes since 2023-01-01 00:00:00" ;
        XTIME:stagger = "" ;
    int64 reftime ;

// global attributes:
        :TITLE = " OUTPUT FROM WRF V4.4.1 MODEL" ;
        :START_DATE = "2023-01-01_00:00:00" ;
        :SIMULATION_START_DATE = "2023-01-01_00:00:00" ;
        :WEST-EAST_GRID_DIMENSION = 316 ;
        :SOUTH-NORTH_GRID_DIMENSION = 244 ;
        :BOTTOM-TOP_GRID_DIMENSION = 50 ;
        :DX = 3000.f ;
        :DY = 3000.f ;
        :AERCU_OPT = 0 ;
        :AERCU_FCT = 1.f ;
        :IDEAL_CASE = 0 ;
        :DIFF_6TH_SLOPEOPT = 0 ;
        :AUTO_LEVELS_OPT = 2 ;
        :DIFF_6TH_THRESH = 0.1f ;
        :DZBOT = 50.f ;
        :DZSTRETCH_S = 1.3f ;
        :DZSTRETCH_U = 1.1f ;
        :SKEBS_ON = 0 ;
        :USE_Q_DIABATIC = 0 ;
        :GRIDTYPE = "C" ;
        :DIFF_OPT = 2 ;
        :KM_OPT = 1 ;
        :DAMP_OPT = 0 ;
        :DAMPCOEF = 0.01f ;
        :KHDIF = 0.f ;
        :KVDIF = 0.f ;
        :MP_PHYSICS = 8 ;
        :RA_LW_PHYSICS = 1 ;
        :RA_SW_PHYSICS = 1 ;
        :SF_SFCLAY_PHYSICS = 2 ;
        :SF_SURFACE_PHYSICS = 2 ;
        :BL_PBL_PHYSICS = 2 ;
        :CU_PHYSICS = 2 ;
        :SF_LAKE_PHYSICS = 0 ;
        :SURFACE_INPUT_SOURCE = 1 ;
        :SST_UPDATE = 0 ;
        :GHG_INPUT = 1 ;
        :GRID_FDDA = 0 ;
        :GFDDA_INTERVAL_M = 0 ;
        :GFDDA_END_H = 0 ;
        :GRID_SFDDA = 0 ;
        :SGFDDA_INTERVAL_M = 0 ;
        :SGFDDA_END_H = 0 ;
        :HYPSOMETRIC_OPT = 2 ;
        :USE_THETA_M = 1 ;
        :GWD_OPT = 0 ;
        :SF_URBAN_PHYSICS = 0 ;
        :SF_SURFACE_MOSAIC = 0 ;
        :SF_OCEAN_PHYSICS = 0 ;
        :SHCU_PHYSICS = 0 ;
        :MFSHCONV = 0 ;
        :FEEDBACK = 1 ;
        :SMOOTH_OPTION = 0 ;
        :SWRAD_SCAT = 1.f ;
        :W_DAMPING = 1 ;
        :DT = 18.f ;
        :RADT = 30.f ;
        :BLDT = 0.f ;
        :CUDT = 5.f ;
        :AER_OPT = 0 ;
        :SWINT_OPT = 0 ;
        :AER_TYPE = 1 ;
        :AER_AOD550_OPT = 1 ;
        :AER_ANGEXP_OPT = 1 ;
        :AER_SSA_OPT = 1 ;
        :AER_ASY_OPT = 1 ;
        :AER_AOD550_VAL = 0.12f ;
        :AER_ANGEXP_VAL = 1.3f ;
        :AER_SSA_VAL = 0.85f ;
        :AER_ASY_VAL = 0.9f ;
        :MOIST_ADV_OPT = 1 ;
        :SCALAR_ADV_OPT = 1 ;
        :TKE_ADV_OPT = 1 ;
        :DIFF_6TH_OPT = 0 ;
        :DIFF_6TH_FACTOR = 0.12f ;
        :OBS_NUDGE_OPT = 0 ;
        :BUCKET_MM = -1.f ;
        :BUCKET_J = -1.f ;
        :PREC_ACC_DT = 0.f ;
        :ISFTCFLX = 0 ;
        :ISHALLOW = 0 ;
        :ISFFLX = 1 ;
        :ICLOUD = 1 ;
        :ICLOUD_CU = 0 ;
        :TRACER_PBLMIX = 1 ;
        :SCALAR_PBLMIX = 0 ;
        :YSU_TOPDOWN_PBLMIX = 1 ;
        :GRAV_SETTLING = 0 ;
        :CLDOVRLP = 2 ;
        :IDCOR = 0 ;
        :DFI_OPT = 0 ;
        :NTASKS_X = 6 ;
        :NTASKS_Y = 8 ;
        :NTASKS_TOTAL = 48 ;
        :SIMULATION_INITIALIZATION_TYPE = "REAL-DATA CASE" ;
        :WEST-EAST_PATCH_START_UNSTAG = 1 ;
        :WEST-EAST_PATCH_END_UNSTAG = 315 ;
        :WEST-EAST_PATCH_START_STAG = 1 ;
        :WEST-EAST_PATCH_END_STAG = 316 ;
        :SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_START_UNSTAG = 1 ;
        :SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_END_UNSTAG = 243 ;
        :SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_START_STAG = 1 ;
        :SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_END_STAG = 244 ;
        :BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_START_UNSTAG = 1 ;
        :BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_END_UNSTAG = 49 ;
        :BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_START_STAG = 1 ;
        :BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_END_STAG = 50 ;
        :GRID_ID = 3 ;
        :PARENT_ID = 2 ;
        :I_PARENT_START = 110 ;
        :J_PARENT_START = 86 ;
        :PARENT_GRID_RATIO = 3 ;
        :CEN_LAT = 27.68596f ;
        :CEN_LON = 84.45547f ;
        :TRUELAT1 = 27.f ;
        :TRUELAT2 = 0.f ;
        :MOAD_CEN_LAT = 26.99998f ;
        :STAND_LON = 86.f ;
        :POLE_LAT = 90.f ;
        :POLE_LON = 0.f ;
        :GMT = 0.f ;
        :JULYR = 2023 ;
        :JULDAY = 1 ;
        :MAP_PROJ = 3 ;
        :MAP_PROJ_CHAR = "Mercator" ;
        :MMINLU = "MODIFIED_IGBP_MODIS_NOAH" ;
        :NUM_LAND_CAT = 21 ;
        :ISWATER = 17 ;
        :ISLAKE = 21 ;
        :ISICE = 15 ;
        :ISURBAN = 13 ;
        :ISOILWATER = 14 ;
        :HYBRID_OPT = 2 ;
        :ETAC = 0.2f ;
        :history = "Tue Apr 18 01:35:55 2023: ncks -v T2 wrfout_d03_2023-01-01_00.nc tempall.nc" ;
        :NCO = "netCDF Operators version 4.9.7 (Homepage = http://nco.sf.net, Code = http://github.com/nco/nco)" ;
}
```

Downloadedncfile.nc

```
netcdf sresa1b_ncar_ccsm3-example {
dimensions:
    lat = 128 ;
    lon = 256 ;
    bnds = 2 ;
    plev = 17 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (1 currently)
variables:
    float area(lat, lon) ;
        area:long_name = "Surface area" ;
        area:units = "meter2" ;
    float lat(lat) ;
        lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        lat:axis = "Y" ;
        lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:bounds = "lat_bnds" ;
    double lat_bnds(lat, bnds) ;
    float lon(lon) ;
        lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        lon:axis = "X" ;
        lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:bounds = "lon_bnds" ;
    double lon_bnds(lon, bnds) ;
    int msk_rgn(lat, lon) ;
        msk_rgn:long_name = "Mask region" ;
        msk_rgn:units = "bool" ;
    double plev(plev) ;
        plev:long_name = "pressure" ;
        plev:units = "Pa" ;
        plev:standard_name = "air_pressure" ;
        plev:positive = "down" ;
        plev:axis = "Z" ;
    float pr(time, lat, lon) ;
        pr:comment = "Created using NCL code CCSM_atmm_2cf.ncl on\n",
            " machine eagle163s" ;
        pr:missing_value = 1.e+20f ;
        pr:_FillValue = 1.e+20f ;
        pr:cell_methods = "time: mean (interval: 1 month)" ;
        pr:history = "(PRECC+PRECL)*r[h2o]" ;
        pr:original_units = "m-1 s-1" ;
        pr:original_name = "PRECC, PRECL" ;
        pr:standard_name = "precipitation_flux" ;
        pr:units = "kg m-2 s-1" ;
        pr:long_name = "precipitation_flux" ;
        pr:cell_method = "time: mean" ;
    float tas(time, lat, lon) ;
        tas:comment = "Created using NCL code CCSM_atmm_2cf.ncl on\n",
            " machine eagle163s" ;
        tas:missing_value = 1.e+20f ;
        tas:_FillValue = 1.e+20f ;
        tas:cell_methods = "time: mean (interval: 1 month)" ;
        tas:history = "Added height coordinate" ;
        tas:coordinates = "height" ;
        tas:original_units = "K" ;
        tas:original_name = "TREFHT" ;
        tas:standard_name = "air_temperature" ;
        tas:units = "K" ;
        tas:long_name = "air_temperature" ;
        tas:cell_method = "time: mean" ;
    double time(time) ;
        time:calendar = "noleap" ;
        time:standard_name = "time" ;
        time:axis = "T" ;
        time:units = "days since 0000-1-1" ;
        time:bounds = "time_bnds" ;
        time:long_name = "time" ;
    double time_bnds(time, bnds) ;
    float ua(time, plev, lat, lon) ;
        ua:comment = "Created using NCL code CCSM_atmm_2cf.ncl on\n",
            " machine eagle163s" ;
        ua:missing_value = 1.e+20f ;
        ua:cell_methods = "time: mean (interval: 1 month)" ;
        ua:long_name = "eastward_wind" ;
        ua:history = "Interpolated U with NCL \'vinth2p_ecmwf\'" ;
        ua:units = "m s-1" ;
        ua:original_units = "m s-1" ;
        ua:original_name = "U" ;
        ua:standard_name = "eastward_wind" ;
        ua:_FillValue = 1.e+20f ;

// global attributes:
        :CVS_Id = "$Id$" ;
        :creation_date = "" ;
        :prg_ID = "Source file unknown Version unknown Date unknown" ;
        :cmd_ln = "bds -x 256 -y 128 -m 23 -o /data/zender/data/dst_T85.nc" ;
        :history = "Tue Oct 25 15:08:51 2005: ncks -O -x -v va -m sresa1b_ncar_ccsm3_0_run1_200001.nc sresa1b_ncar_ccsm3_0_run1_200001.nc\n",
            "Tue Oct 25 15:07:21 2005: ncks -d time,0 sresa1b_ncar_ccsm3_0_run1_200001_201912.nc sresa1b_ncar_ccsm3_0_run1_200001.nc\n",
            "Tue Oct 25 13:29:43 2005: ncks -d time,0,239 sresa1b_ncar_ccsm3_0_run1_200001_209912.nc /var/www/html/tmp/sresa1b_ncar_ccsm3_0_run1_200001_201912.nc\n",
            "Thu Oct 20 10:47:50 2005: ncks -A -v va /data/brownmc/sresa1b/atm/mo/va/ncar_ccsm3_0/run1/sresa1b_ncar_ccsm3_0_run1_va_200001_209912.nc /data/brownmc/sresa1b/atm/mo/tas/ncar_ccsm3_0/run1/sresa1b_ncar_ccsm3_0_run1_200001_209912.nc\n",
            "Wed Oct 19 14:55:04 2005: ncks -F -d time,01,1200 /data/brownmc/sresa1b/atm/mo/va/ncar_ccsm3_0/run1/sresa1b_ncar_ccsm3_0_run1_va_200001_209912.nc /data/brownmc/sresa1b/atm/mo/va/ncar_ccsm3_0/run1/sresa1b_ncar_ccsm3_0_run1_va_200001_209912.nc\n",
            "Wed Oct 19 14:53:28 2005: ncrcat /data/brownmc/sresa1b/atm/mo/va/ncar_ccsm3_0/run1/foo_05_1200.nc /data/brownmc/sresa1b/atm/mo/va/ncar_ccsm3_0/run1/foo_1192_1196.nc /data/brownmc/sresa1b/atm/mo/va/ncar_ccsm3_0/run1/sresa1b_ncar_ccsm3_0_run1_va_200001_209912.nc\n",
            "Wed Oct 19 14:50:38 2005: ncks -F -d time,05,1200 /data/brownmc/sresa1b/atm/mo/va/ncar_ccsm3_0/run1/va_A1.SRESA1B_1.CCSM.atmm.2000-01_cat_2099-12.nc /data/brownmc/sresa1b/atm/mo/va/ncar_ccsm3_0/run1/foo_05_1200.nc\n",
            "Wed Oct 19 14:49:45 2005: ncrcat /data/brownmc/sresa1b/atm/mo/va/ncar_ccsm3_0/run1/va_A1.SRESA1B_1.CCSM.atmm.2000-01_cat_2079-12.nc /data/brownmc/sresa1b/atm/mo/va/ncar_ccsm3_0/run1/va_A1.SRESA1B_1.CCSM.atmm.2080-01_cat_2099-12.nc /data/brownmc/sresa1b/atm/mo/va/ncar_ccsm3_0/run1/va_A1.SRESA1B_1.CCSM.atmm.2000-01_cat_2099-12.nc\n",
            "Created from CCSM3 case b30.040a\n",
            " by wgstrand@ucar.edu\n",
            " on Wed Nov 17 14:12:57 EST 2004\n",
            " \n",
            " For all data, added IPCC requested metadata" ;
        :table_id = "Table A1" ;
        :title = "model output prepared for IPCC AR4" ;
        :institution = "NCAR (National Center for Atmospheric \n",
            "Research, Boulder, CO, USA)" ;
        :source = "CCSM3.0, version beta19 (2004): \n",
            "atmosphere: CAM3.0, T85L26;\n",
            "ocean     : POP1.4.3 (modified), gx1v3\n",
            "sea ice   : CSIM5.0, T85;\n",
            "land      : CLM3.0, gx1v3" ;
        :contact = "ccsm@ucar.edu" ;
        :project_id = "IPCC Fourth Assessment" ;
        :Conventions = "CF-1.0" ;
        :references = "Collins, W.D., et al., 2005:\n",
            " The Community Climate System Model, Version 3\n",
            " Journal of Climate\n",
            " \n",
            " Main website: http://www.ccsm.ucar.edu" ;
        :acknowledgment = " Any use of CCSM data should acknowledge the contribution\n",
            " of the CCSM project and CCSM sponsor agencies with the \n",
            " following citation:\n",
            " \'This research uses data provided by the Community Climate\n",
            " System Model project (www.ccsm.ucar.edu), supported by the\n",
            " Directorate for Geosciences of the National Science Foundation\n",
            " and the Office of Biological and Environmental Research of\n",
            " the U.S. Department of Energy.\'\n",
            "In addition, the words \'Community Climate System Model\' and\n",
            " \'CCSM\' should be included as metadata for webpages referencing\n",
            " work using CCSM data or as keywords provided to journal or book\n",
            "publishers of your manuscripts.\n",
            "Users of CCSM data accept the responsibility of emailing\n",
            " citations of publications of research using CCSM data to\n",
            " ccsm@ucar.edu.\n",
            "Any redistribution of CCSM data must include this data\n",
            " acknowledgement statement." ;
        :realization = 1 ;
        :experiment_id = "720 ppm stabilization experiment (SRESA1B)" ;
        :comment = "This simulation was initiated from year 2000 of \n",
            " CCSM3 model run b30.030a and executed on \n",
            " hardware cheetah.ccs.ornl.gov. The input external forcings are\n",
            "ozone forcing    : A1B.ozone.128x64_L18_1991-2100_c040528.nc\n",
            "aerosol optics   : AerosolOptics_c040105.nc\n",
            "aerosol MMR      : AerosolMass_V_128x256_clim_c031022.nc\n",
            "carbon scaling   : carbonscaling_A1B_1990-2100_c040609.nc\n",
            "solar forcing    : Fixed at 1366.5 W m-2\n",
            "GHGs             : ghg_ipcc_A1B_1870-2100_c040521.nc\n",
            "GHG loss rates   : noaamisc.r8.nc\n",
            "volcanic forcing : none\n",
            "DMS emissions    : DMS_emissions_128x256_clim_c040122.nc\n",
            "oxidants         : oxid_128x256_L26_clim_c040112.nc\n",
            "SOx emissions    : SOx_emissions_A1B_128x256_L2_1990-2100_c040608.nc\n",
            " Physical constants used for derived data:\n",
            " Lv (latent heat of evaporation): 2.501e6 J kg-1\n",
            " Lf (latent heat of fusion     ): 3.337e5 J kg-1\n",
            " r[h2o] (density of water      ): 1000 kg m-3\n",
            " g2kg   (grams to kilograms    ): 1000 g kg-1\n",
            " \n",
            " Integrations were performed by NCAR and CRIEPI with support\n",
            " and facilities provided by NSF, DOE, MEXT and ESC/JAMSTEC." ;
        :model_name_english = "NCAR CCSM" ;
```

I also tried the modified image of GeoServer from meteofi/geoserver, and still had the same problem. How can I load my NetCDF file into GeoServer?